# Issue associated with submodule checkout in vsts build

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am having issues with building a solution which has an associated submodule, on Hosted VS2017 agent. While reading the logs I identified that the build step is not building the submodule first because of which the references are not getting resolved.
Any idea on what I might be missing?

I am checking out submodules in the get sources step:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gOws.png]

My build task:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA7cR.png]

Answer (score 0):

> I identified that the build step is not building the submodule first
>   because of which the references are not getting resolved.

If the main repo has the references from the submodule repo (such as dlls), you do should build the submodule repo firstly.

While in VS Build task, you only specify the `SHTAdminSync/SHTAdminSync.sln` (seems the solution existing in the main repo). So you should add another VS Build task before build the main repo’s solution:

Before the VS Build task (Build solution SHTAdminSync/SHTAdminSync.sln), add another VS Build task, and specify the solution from the submodule repo, such as `subrepo/projectname/projectname.sln`.

Comment: But if i select checkout submodules in get sources, wont it implicitly build the submodules first?

Comment: No, It only download the submodules in Get sources step.

Comment: @AmritKanungo did you build successful after adding VS build task in your definition?

Comment: Ya i tried that method but it dint work. The references were not getting resolved. I was on vacation and have not tried any other ways. May be I am missing something while adding the references. have to check that